# Deadlock on async GCD using XMPPFramework

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch, xmppframework

As our app has been getting bigger and bigger, we started to notice deadlocks inside the XMPPFramework CoreDataStorage's scheduleBlock: method, shown below:

```
- (void)scheduleBlock:(dispatch_block_t)block
{
    // By design this method should not be invoked from the storageQueue.
    // 
    // If you remove the assert statement below, you are destroying the sole purpose for this class,
    // which is to optimize the disk IO by buffering save operations.
    // 
    NSAssert(!dispatch_get_specific(storageQueueTag), @"Invoked on incorrect queue");
    // 
    // For a full discussion of this method, please see XMPPCoreDataStorageProtocol.h
    // 
    // dispatch_Async
    //          ^

    OSAtomicIncrement32(&pendingRequests);
    dispatch_async(storageQueue, ^{ @autoreleasepool {

        block();
        [self maybeSave:OSAtomicDecrement32(&pendingRequests)];
    }});
}
```

Although it happens inside a framework, I do believe this issue is pertinent to the whole GCD discussion, since it happens only in very specific situations (in our case, it was first reported only through a stress test) and the code mentioned above works perfectly for the great majority of cases.

What we have noticed is that if this method is called many times in a short period of time, suddenly it will generate a deadlock. As our logs pointed out, one of the calls with enter the dispatch_async, but never "leave it". The following ones will only increment the "pendingRequests" variable, "hitting" a blocked storageQueue and never being executed.

This issue does not seem to be easy to reproduce. In our tests, we launch between 2 and 5 calls to the method every second. The deadlock happens randomly somewhere between 5 and 50 seconds. Depending on the number of calls per second and other adjustments, you can postpone this to somewhere around 150 seconds, but it does not solve the issue (the deadlock will still happen, just later). It might also be important to mention that the calls to this methods come from different threads, including the mainThread.

Since the issue is very hard to reproduce through "common means", at least in our app, it should not be critic. However, we are now afraid that this might happen "randomly" for our users. We do not feel "safe" with the method anymore, specially in terms of scaling.

So, we would like to start and join a further discussion around this, which is a pretty conventional use for GCD. If anyone finds a possible point of failure in the method, or if anyone would like to suggest a different approach or point out to some different practices, it would all be very welcome.

EDIT 1 - This is a log showing a deadlock. I've numbered the lines to make it easier to discuss. You will notice that everything went smoothly until line 30. There, a block is schedule in XMPPMessageArchivingCoreDataStorage, coming from the main thread. Right after, another block is scheduled, now coming from thread 11. Neither of these will get to be executed. On lines 33 and 35, you will notice that the queue starts to build, but the storage thread is never "released", so none of the queued operations will ever be executed.

```
1 - Oct 19 16:45:18 Ronaldo-Juniors-iPhone: Event #30 started
2 - Oct 19 16:45:18 Ronaldo-Juniors-iPhone: Will Schedule Block -> 0 pending requests - Storage Queue: <OS_dispatch_queue: XMPPMessageArchivingCoreDataStorage[0x15d5c8c90]> / Caller Thread: <NSThread: 0x15e9caaf0>{number = 16, name = (null)}
3 - Oct 19 16:45:18 Ronaldo-Juniors-iPhone: Dispatched Scheduled Block at storage queue <OS_dispatch_queue: XMPPMessageArchivingCoreDataStorage[0x15d5c8c90]> / Schedule Block Thread: <NSThread: 0x15e9caaf0>{number = 16, name = (null)}
4 - Oct 19 16:45:18 Ronaldo-Juniors-iPhone: Did Finish Schedule Block -> 0 pending requests - Storage Queue :<OS_dispatch_queue: XMPPMessageArchivingCoreDataStorage[0x15d5c8c90]>
5 - Oct 19 16:45:18 Ronaldo-Juniors-iPhone: Will Schedule Block -> 0 pending requests - Storage Queue: <OS_dispatch_queue: XMPPMessageArchivingCoreDataStorage[0x15d5c8c90]> / Caller Thread: <NSThread: 0x15d51a0a0>{number = 1, name = main}
6 - Oct 19 16:45:18 Ronaldo-Juniors-iPhone: Will Schedule Block -> 0 pending requests - Storage Queue: <OS_dispatch_queue: XMPPRosterCoreDataStorage[0x15d5c7ec0]> / Caller Thread: <NSThread: 0x15d51a0a0>{number = 1, name = main}
7 - Oct 19 16:45:18 Ronaldo-Juniors-iPhone: Dispatched Scheduled Block at storage queue <OS_dispatch_queue: XMPPRosterCoreDataStorage[0x15d5c7ec0]> / Schedule Block Thread: <NSThread: 0x15e972c30>{number = 18, name = (null)}
8 - Oct 19 16:45:18 Ronaldo-Juniors-iPhone: Will Schedule Block -> 1 pending requests - Storage Queue: <OS_dispatch_queue: XMPPMessageArchivingCoreDataStorage[0x15d5c8c90]> / Caller Thread: <NSThread: 0x15d6bf4a0>{number = 7, name = (null)}
9 - Oct 19 16:45:18 Ronaldo-Juniors-iPhone: Dispatched Scheduled Block at storage queue <OS_dispatch_queue: XMPPMessageArchivingCoreDataStorage[0x15d5c8c90]> / Schedule Block Thread: <NSThread: 0x15e9caaf0>{number = 16, name = (null)}
10 - Oct 19 16:45:18 Ronaldo-Juniors-iPhone: Did Finish Schedule Block -> 1 pending requests - Storage Queue :<OS_dispatch_queue: XMPPMessageArchivingCoreDataStorage[0x15d5c8c90]>
11 - Oct 19 16:45:18 Ronaldo-Juniors-iPhone: Did Finish Schedule Block -> 0 pending requests - Storage Queue :<OS_dispatch_queue: XMPPRosterCoreDataStorage[0x15d5c7ec0]>
12 - Oct 19 16:45:18 Ronaldo-Juniors-iPhone: Will Schedule Block -> 1 pending requests - Storage Queue: <OS_dispatch_queue: XMPPMessageArchivingCoreDataStorage[0x15d5c8c90]> / Caller Thread: <NSThread: 0x15d51a0a0>{number = 1, name = main}
13 - Oct 19 16:45:18 Ronaldo-Juniors-iPhone: Dispatched Scheduled Block at storage queue <OS_dispatch_queue: XMPPMessageArchivingCoreDataStorage[0x15d5c8c90]> / Schedule Block Thread: <NSThread: 0x15e9caaf0>{number = 16, name = (null)}
14 - Oct 19 16:45:18 Ronaldo-Juniors-iPhone: Did Finish Schedule Block -> 1 pending requests - Storage Queue :<OS_dispatch_queue: XMPPMessageArchivingCoreDataStorage[0x15d5c8c90]>
15 - Oct 19 16:45:18 Ronaldo-Juniors-iPhone: Dispatched Scheduled Block at storage queue <OS_dispatch_queue: XMPPMessageArchivingCoreDataStorage[0x15d5c8c90]> / Schedule Block Thread: <NSThread: 0x15e9caaf0>{number = 16, name = (null)}
16 - Oct 19 16:45:18 Ronaldo-Juniors-iPhone: Did Finish Schedule Block -> 0 pending requests - Storage Queue :<OS_dispatch_queue: XMPPMessageArchivingCoreDataStorage[0x15d5c8c90]>
17 - Oct 19 16:45:19 Ronaldo-Juniors-iPhone: Will Schedule Block -> 0 pending requests - Storage Queue: <OS_dispatch_queue: XMPPMessageArchivingCoreDataStorage[0x15d5c8c90]> / Caller Thread: <NSThread: 0x15e9caaf0>{number = 16, name = (null)}
18 - Oct 19 16:45:19 Ronaldo-Juniors-iPhone: Dispatched Scheduled Block at storage queue <OS_dispatch_queue: XMPPMessageArchivingCoreDataStorage[0x15d5c8c90]> / Schedule Block Thread: <NSThread: 0x15e9caaf0>{number = 16, name = (null)}
19 - Oct 19 16:45:19 Ronaldo-Juniors-iPhone: Did Finish Schedule Block -> 0 pending requests - Storage Queue :<OS_dispatch_queue: XMPPMessageArchivingCoreDataStorage[0x15d5c8c90]>
20 - Oct 19 16:45:19 Ronaldo-Juniors-iPhone: Will Schedule Block -> 0 pending requests - Storage Queue: <OS_dispatch_queue: XMPPMessageArchivingCoreDataStorage[0x15d5c8c90]> / Caller Thread: <NSThread: 0x15d6bf4a0>{number = 7, name = (null)}
21 - Oct 19 16:45:19 Ronaldo-Juniors-iPhone: Event #31 started
22 - Oct 19 16:45:19 Ronaldo-Juniors-iPhone: Will Schedule Block -> 1 pending requests - Storage Queue: <OS_dispatch_queue: XMPPMessageArchivingCoreDataStorage[0x15d5c8c90]> / Caller Thread: <NSThread: 0x15d51a0a0>{number = 1, name = main}
23 - Oct 19 16:45:19 Ronaldo-Juniors-iPhone: Will Schedule Block -> 0 pending requests - Storage Queue: <OS_dispatch_queue: XMPPRosterCoreDataStorage[0x15d5c7ec0]> / Caller Thread: <NSThread: 0x15d51a0a0>{number = 1, name = main}
24 - Oct 19 16:45:19 Ronaldo-Juniors-iPhone: Dispatched Scheduled Block at storage queue <OS_dispatch_queue: XMPPRosterCoreDataStorage[0x15d5c7ec0]> / Schedule Block Thread: <NSThread: 0x15e972c30>{number = 18, name = (null)}
25 - Oct 19 16:45:19 Ronaldo-Juniors-iPhone: Did Finish Schedule Block -> 0 pending requests - Storage Queue :<OS_dispatch_queue: XMPPRosterCoreDataStorage[0x15d5c7ec0]>
26 - Oct 19 16:45:19 Ronaldo-Juniors-iPhone: Dispatched Scheduled Block at storage queue <OS_dispatch_queue: XMPPMessageArchivingCoreDataStorage[0x15d5c8c90]> / Schedule Block Thread: <NSThread: 0x15e9caaf0>{number = 16, name = (null)}
27 - Oct 19 16:45:19 Ronaldo-Juniors-iPhone: Did Finish Schedule Block -> 1 pending requests - Storage Queue :<OS_dispatch_queue: XMPPMessageArchivingCoreDataStorage[0x15d5c8c90]>
28 - Oct 19 16:45:19 Ronaldo-Juniors-iPhone: Dispatched Scheduled Block at storage queue <OS_dispatch_queue: XMPPMessageArchivingCoreDataStorage[0x15d5c8c90]> / Schedule Block Thread: <NSThread: 0x15e9caaf0>{number = 16, name = (null)}
29 - Oct 19 16:45:19 Ronaldo-Juniors-iPhone: Did Finish Schedule Block -> 0 pending requests - Storage Queue :<OS_dispatch_queue: XMPPMessageArchivingCoreDataStorage[0x15d5c8c90]>
30 - Oct 19 16:45:19 Ronaldo-Juniors-iPhone: Will Schedule Block -> 0 pending requests - Storage Queue: <OS_dispatch_queue: XMPPMessageArchivingCoreDataStorage[0x15d5c8c90]> / Caller Thread: <NSThread: 0x15d51a0a0>{number = 1, name = main}
31 - Oct 19 16:45:20 Ronaldo-Juniors-iPhone: Will Schedule Block -> 1 pending requests - Storage Queue: <OS_dispatch_queue: XMPPMessageArchivingCoreDataStorage[0x15d5c8c90]> / Caller Thread: <NSThread: 0x15eaf8a50>{number = 11, name = (null)}
32 - Oct 19 16:45:20 Ronaldo-Juniors-iPhone: Event #32 started
33 - Oct 19 16:45:20 Ronaldo-Juniors-iPhone: Will Schedule Block -> 2 pending requests - Storage Queue: <OS_dispatch_queue: XMPPMessageArchivingCoreDataStorage[0x15d5c8c90]> / Caller Thread: <NSThread: 0x15d51a0a0>{number = 1, name = main}
34 - Oct 19 16:45:20 Ronaldo-Juniors-iPhone: Will Schedule Block -> 0 pending requests - Storage Queue: <OS_dispatch_queue: XMPPRosterCoreDataStorage[0x15d5c7ec0]> / Caller Thread: <NSThread: 0x15d51a0a0>{number = 1, name = main}
35 - Oct 19 16:45:20 Ronaldo-Juniors-iPhone: Will Schedule Block -> 3 pending requests - Storage Queue: <OS_dispatch_queue: XMPPMessageArchivingCoreDataStorage[0x15d5c8c90]> / Caller Thread: <NSThread: 0x15eaf8a50>{number = 11, name = (null)}
36 - Oct 19 16:45:20 Ronaldo-Juniors-iPhone: Dispatched Scheduled Block at storage queue <OS_dispatch_queue: XMPPRosterCoreDataStorage[0x15d5c7ec0]> / Schedule Block Thread: <NSThread: 0x15eaf8a50>{number = 11, name = (null)}
```

Comment: What do your blocks typically do?  Do they call back to a specific thread?

Comment: They do a core data fetch request and send the results to another block. Important to note that each of them access a different core data entity.

Comment: Does the "other block" run on the same thread as the caller, or is it scheduled?

Also, can you break into the debugger and see which threads are waiting?

Comment: The other blocks runs on the same thread as the caller. I edited the question to include a log showing the deadlock.

Comment: If you break into the debugger at the point where requests start to queue, you should see one or more threads in psync_wait.  If you don't, you probably don't have a deadlock, but rather something else is blocking the queue.

Comment: This problem doesn't happen when connected to the debugger. What I did was to run the app, wait for it to happen and only then connect the debugger. Thanks to your suggestion, I found a thread locked in a "objc_sync_enter" call.

Looking through the code, I found that one of the blocks called by the scheduled block would, later on, call a method which used "objc_sync_enter" and "objc_sync_exit". And this method would be the cause for random lock.

It is still not clear for me why this is causing the issue, but the removal of the sync functions inside that method solved it.

Comment: Obviously, the sync was trying to sync on a locked object and whatever had it locked wasn't going to let go.  Without knowing what object was being synced on, along with myriad other details of your app, there's not more to say :-)  Glad you were able to clear out your locking issues!